# Firestore Rules, allow update only certain fields

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following database collection `'/player_profiles/{userId}'`.  I want to use the rule that only the `request.auth.uid == userId` unless they are only updating the field matches which is an array.  I tried this, but it denied permissions

```
match /player_profiles/{userId}{
        allow write: if userId == request.auth.uid; 
      allow update: if (request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(["matches"]) && request.auth != null);
    }
```

And here is the Flutter code that runs the update to add in the item to the matches array:

```
await DatabaseProvider()
        .db
        .collection(PLAYER_COLLECTION)
        .document(widget.userProfile.userId)
        .updateData({
      'matches': FieldValue.arrayUnion([profile.userId])
    });
```

Im new to firestore rules but i thought this would work

Was able to get the behavior I wanted with this:

```
match /player_profiles/{userId}{
        allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId || (request.auth != null && request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["matches"]));
    }
```

Looking at @Doug Stevenson's answer though I can add in making sure they only are allowed to put in their own userId into other peoples profiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request.resource.data.keys()` always contains every field in the document being written, regardless of whether or not it's being updated.  You should use the new [MapDiff](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff) API instead to compare what's being written with what currently exists.

I think you will want to do something like this:

```
if
  (request.resource.data.diff(request.resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["matches"]) &&
  (request.resource.data.matches.toSet().difference(resource.data.matches) == [userId].toSet()) ||
  request.auth == null;
```

I have not tested, but I think you get the idea.  You will need to make liberal use of the linked API documentation for security rules to work with maps, sets, and lists effectively.